# Downloading OSM map tiles to QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, openlayers

In QGIS, is there any plugin that can download OSM map tiles once save it and not have to download it every time I scroll move on the canvas?

I use OpenLayers for now, but what if I do not have internet connection?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) pluging (it also cache tiles according to settings) to add one of [800 basemaps](https://qms.nextgis.com/) to QGIS. And [QTiles](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/) plugin to save the map contents as tiles (Folder or MBTiles).

- The short video for QMS: https://youtu.be/JR7XLNw-esQ
- The short video for QTiles: https://youtu.be/G_d8BN2pHLE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the OpenLayers plugin, you can use the [TileLayer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/) plugin. It allows to add locally stored tilesets. Note that the configuration file is **tab** delimitered. The plugin allows you to save the tiles you just view too.

QGIS does not offer a tile download service, but there are several apps listed in the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Tile_downloading). Please obey the rules about bulk downloading, otherwise your IP will be blacklisted.

Comment: Is there any guide online on how to set up the plugin? I am having difficulties on how to add the tiles.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin? Otherwise go through my answers at http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=[qgis]TileLayer.